# Implementing a class from another directory - Android

Tags: android, inheritance, abstract-class, bottomnavigationview

I am working with a bottomNavigationBar, and I have a class

```
 navBase4 extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

All my classes that use my bottomNavigationBar implement this class, and it handles highlighting the selected icon, opening new actives etc.

For example, another class that is in the same directory as navBase4 is

```
public class userProfile extends navBase4
```

But I just created a new class

```
public class updateInfo extends navBase4
```

That is in a a sub directory of the folder containing navBase4. when I try to implement the methods that navBase4 requrires I get an error that says :
Class 'updateInfo' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'getContentViewId()' in 'navBase4

Why does it work when the class is in the same directory as navBase4 but not if it is in a subdirectory?

navBase4 code:

```
public abstract class navBase4 extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

protected BottomNavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentViewId());
    navigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    doCustomStuffOnStart();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    //move to a new activity on item selected
}

protected void updateNavigationBarState(){
    //update state
}

void selectBottomNavigationBarItem(int itemId) {
    //do stuff
}

abstract int getContentViewId();

abstract int getNavigationMenuItemId();

abstract void doCustomStuffOnStart();

}
```

updateInfo code - this one throws the error

```
public class updateInfo extends navBase4 {

private TextView mTextMessage;

@Override
int getContentViewId() {
    return R.layout.activity_user_profile;
}

@Override
int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
    return R.id.navigation_user_profile;
}

@Override
void doCustomStuffOnStart() {

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_info);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

}

File directory

userProfile:

-navBase4

-userProfile

folder: subPages contains updateInfo

Comment: FYI: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the directory.  navBase4 is an abstract class.  If you want to make a non-abstract child, you need to provide an implementation for all non-abstract methods.

Also, your code is going to be broken-  if you're using a system where you return a content view id like that, you do NOT want to call setContentView in the child class.  Call it only in the parent class.  Otherwise views the parent view uses findViewById to find will not be on screen as the content view gets overridden.

Comment: the thing is I do implement all the abstract classes.... that's why I was a little confused